# Python get exec-code of subprocess

Tags: python

On Win7 I want to get exec-code (return code) of EXE GUI process. It may return int. It's easy with `subprocess`?

Py3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The droid you are looking for is `subprocess.check_call` (quoting from the API docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html
I've quoted below for convenience...

```
subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)

"""
Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the return code was zero then 
return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the 
return code in the returncode attribute.

The arguments shown above are merely the most common ones, described below in Frequently 
Used Arguments (hence the slightly odd notation in the abbreviated signature). The full   
function signature is the same as that of the Popen constructor - this functions passes    
all supplied arguments directly through to that interface.
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `subprocess.check_output`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

I made such def now (fn is full path of exe)

```
import subprocess
def get_exec_code(fn, code=0):
    try:
        subprocess.check_call([fn, str(code)])
        return 0
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return e.returncode
```